# How do I access the file system as a root or owner?

Tags: filesystem, root, permissions

I need to add online store configuration files in file system `var/www`. but I can't access the file system, because it says that only owner can access it, the owner is `root`.

So, how can I access those files? Or is it possible for me to use my file system as a owner?

I need to create a directory named `ubuntu` in `var/www` and store my online store configuration files.

Answer (score 2):

By default `/var/www` is owned by root:root and no one but the admin can add or change files there. You need to set contents of `/var/www/` to the correct permissions.  There are several methods but the one I use: set the group to `www-data` and add your user to that group.

Setting group `www-data`:

```
sudo chgrp -R www-data /var/www/ubuntu
```

Add your user to `www-data`:

```
sudo usermod -a -G www-data $USER
```

That way you are part of the group that can write inside `/var/www/`.

But I would start by reading the documentation that you got with the webserver since this is just a small part in setting the correct and secure permissions. Directories tend to have permissions set to `755` or `775` and files to `644` or `664` depending on who you want to be able to do things.

Comment: If I remember correctly, new user groups are only applied to new sessions, so after calling `usermod`, you need to log out and back in.

Comment: @DavidFoerster yes it is required to update the desktop settings. Not for a shell ("newgrp" can be used to update a new shell for the time being)

Answer (score 1):

Try `sudo -s` command in terminal. But make sure you know what you’re doing.

Also, if you don’t want to mess with terminal, you can press ALT+F2 and enter `gksu nautilus`. This will open a file manager window from root user.

Comment: Also, if you don’t want to mess with terminal, you can press `ALT+F2` and enter `gksu nautilus`. This will open a file manager window from root user.

Comment: and may I know what should I do next?? as I am new to ubuntu it would be grt if you explain me in detail!!

Comment: @AleksandrChepurnoy please put that part from your comment into your answer.

Answer (score 0):

A more GUI friendly way is using the gksu command in terminal it gives you a little pop up box and type in Nautilus to open it as root

Comment: I would not assume that he has a desktop ;) This sounds more like a (hosted) server.